# Redirecting stdin and stdout?

Tags: c, io

So im trying to redirect the I/O to read command from file then when user runs the output command it will print the compiled command to output file.

For example on the terminal:

```
./run 2 < test.txt // This would take file using dup and take the input
```

Then when you want to output the compile:

```
./run 1 > output.txt // and it would put into an output file
```

So far i know how to output to a file but my problem is with the input. how do i get the command from the file using the `dup2()` function? I tried researching this but no luck.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char inputForOutput[100];

void functionOutput(int argc, char **argv){

    int ofd; //Init of file desc.

    ofd = open(argv[1], O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_WRONLY);

    dup2(ofd, 1);//Duplicates to stdout

    system("ls");//Copies commnd given to output_file
}

//Function is called when argument number is == 1
void functionInput(int argc, char **argv){
    FILE *ifd;
        printf("\n %s \n ", argv[2]);
    ifd = fopen(argv[2] , "r");
    if (ifd == NULL){
        perror("No file found");
        exit(1);
    }
    fscanf(ifd,"%s",inputForOutput);
    printf("\n**%s**\n",inputForOutput);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int output;
    int input;
    output = strcmp("1", argv[1]);
    input = strcmp("2" ,argv[1]);
    if (output == 0 ) { //Fail safe for number of arguments
        functionOutput(argc, argv);
    }
    else if ( input == 0){
        functionInput(argc, argv);
    }
    else{
        fprintf(stderr, "How to use: %s function output_file\n", argv[0]); // FAIL SAFE IF INPUT DOES NOT MATCH BOTH FUNCTIONS
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect input and output, use this format

> ```
> myprogram > out.txt < in.txt //read from in.txt, write to out.txt
> myprogram < in.txt > out.txt //read from in.txt, write to out.txt
> myprogram < in.txt //redirect stdin only
> myprogram > out.txt //redirect stdout only
> myprogram //no redirection
> ...
> ```

This should work with any program. Example:

```
int main(void)
{
    char buf[1000];
    if(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin))
        printf("write: %s\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

To redirect stdin/stdout in the program, use the standard method

```
freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
printf("Testing...");
fclose(stdout);

freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
char buf[100];
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
fclose(stdin);
```

Alternatively, set `FILE *fin = stdin; FILE* fout = stdout;` to redirect the opposite way.

Next, to write a program using `argv` elements, always test `argc` first. The code below shows an example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int redirect(int argc, char **argv, int *index)
{
    //no more redirection!
    if(*index >= argc)
        return 1;

    //not enough parameters
    if(*index + 1 >= argc)
    {
        printf("wrong usage\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if(strcmp(argv[*index], "<") == 0)
    {
        *index++; //next parameter is to redirect input
        if(!freopen(argv[*index], "r", stdin))
            printf("error, redirect input failed");
    }
    else if(strcmp(argv[*index], ">") == 0)
    {
        *index++; //next parameter is to redirect output
        if(!freopen(argv[*index], "w", stdout))
            printf("error, redirect output failed");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("wrong usage\n");
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int index = 1;
    if(!redirect(argc, argv, &index))
        return 1;

    if(!redirect(argc, argv, &index))
        return 1;

    //read
    char buf[1000];
    if(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin))
    {
        //write
        printf("write: %s\n", buf);
    }

    fclose(stdin);
    fclose(stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yeah but how do i do it if the user wants to enter input in one command and output in anther command

Comment: I don't know what you mean

Comment: sorry. what i meant was, this code does not compile whats in the input text, it just does the print statement. How do i compile, for example, 'ls' which is written in the input file.

Comment: If the code does not compile on your system then explain the error. I changed the format so it should handle any redirection. See the modified usage.

Comment: its compiling but when it runs to does not do anything. I ran the gcc to fie c file, ran ./.out then wrote <text.txt but it prints write: text.txt and thats it

Comment: @NeverSleepAlwaysCode you would need to attempt a non-blocking read of `STDIN_FILENO` using, e.g. `select` or `poll` to test whether there was input waiting.

Comment: how would i use that?

Comment: sorry not familiar with it

Comment: See [select(2) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) (it has an example at the end). You can also see the man page for `poll`. Basically they tell you if input is ready on a given file descriptor allowing you to tell if there is input to read. (if not, the user wants to output in your case)

Answer (score 0):

With `functionOutput()` you have a good first attempt at capturing the output of a system command to a file. Actually, *that* is the function called when the first argument is `1`, so you might want to update your comment. Also, you're creating a file with the name stored in `argv[1]`, which we already know is `1` so it's probably not doing what you expect, and you probably want:

```
ofd = open(argv[2], O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_WRONLY);
```

With `functionInput()` you're reading the first non-whitespace entry from the file. If you're telling it to read the file which you output using the `functionOutput()` function, that is likely to be (some of) the name of the first file which was listed by `ls`.

I'm finding it unclear what you're wanting to do which isn't that. If you want to find out what the command was which you ran to generate the output, that information is not available from the file itself, because you didn't write it there. If that's what you want, you may want to consider writing the command as the first line of the file, followed by the output. Then when you read it, you can assume that the first line is the command run, followed by the output of that command.

Comment: What i want my code to is read a command from file, then compile it and print output to a file.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, and you want to run your program in essentially two different modes, (1) you want to take input if there is input to be taken on `stdin`; and (2) if there is no input waiting, you want to do an output, then `select/pselect` or `poll` are what you are looking for.

For example `select` allows you to check whether there is input ready to be read on a file descriptor (or set of descriptors) and it will return the number of descriptors with input waiting (or `-1` and set `errno` on error). You could simply use the `STDIN_FILENO` (a/k/a fd `0`) to check if there is input on `stdin`, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>         /* for STDIN_FILENO */
#include <sys/select.h>     /* for pselect   */

int input (int filedes)
{
    fd_set set;

    /* declare/initialize zero timeout */
    struct timespec timeout = { .tv_sec = 0 };

    /* Initialize the file descriptor set. */
    FD_ZERO (&set);
    FD_SET (filedes, &set);

    /* check whether input is ready on filedes */
    return pselect (filedes + 1, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout, NULL);
}

int main (void)
{
    if (input (STDIN_FILENO))
        puts ("doing input routine");
    else
        puts ("doing output routine");

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** from the man page "`select()` uses a timeout that is a `struct timeval` (with seconds and microseconds), while `pselect()` uses a `struct timespec` (with seconds and nanoseconds).")

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/select_peekstdin < file
doing input routine

$ ./bin/select_peekstdin
doing output routine
```